# Get a dictionary from a class?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I want to:

1. Take a list of lists
2. Make a frequency table in a dictionary
3. Do things with the resulting dictionary

The class works, the code works, the frequency table is correct.

I want to get a class that returns a dictionary, but I actually get a class that returns a class type.

I can see that it has the right content in there, but I just can't get it out.

Can someone show me how to turn the output of the class to a dictionary type?

I am working with [HN post data](https://www.kaggle.com/hacker-news/hacker-news-posts). Columns, a few thousand rows.

```
freq_pph = {}
freq_cph = {}
freq_uph = {}

# Creates a binned frequency table:
# - key is bin_minutes (size of bin in minutes).
# - value is freq_value which sums/counts the number of things in that column. 
class BinFreq:
  def __init__(self, dataset, bin_minutes, freq_value, dict_name):
    self.dataset = dataset
    self.bin_minutes = bin_minutes
    self.freq_value = freq_value
    self.dict_name = dict_name

  def make_table(self):
    # Sets bin size
    # Counts how of posts in that timedelta
    if (self.bin_minutes == 60) and (self.freq_value == "None"):
      for post in self.dataset:
        hour_dt = post[-1]
        hour_str = hour_dt.strftime("%H")
        if hour_str in self.dict_name:
           self.dict_name[hour_str] += 1
        else:
           self.dict_name[hour_str] = 1
    # Sets bins size
    # Sums the values of a given index/column
    if (self.bin_minutes == 60) and (self.freq_value != "None"):
      for post in self.dataset:
        hour_dt = post[-1]
        hour_str = hour_dt.strftime("%H")
        if hour_str in self.dict_name:
          self.dict_name[hour_str] += int(row[self.freq_value])
        else:
          self.dict_name[hour_str] = int(row[self.freq_value])
```

Instantiate:

```
pph = BinFreq(ask_posts, 60, "None", freq_pph)
pph.make_table()
```

How can `pph` be turned into a real dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `make_table` function to return a dictionary, then you have to add a `return` statement at the end of it, for example: `return self.dict_name`.

If you then want to use it outside of the class, you have to assign it to a variable, so in the second snipped do: `my_dict = pph.make_table()`.

Comment: And that's the info I needed for this exercise. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Classes can't return things – functions in classes could. However, the function in your class doesn't; it just modifies `self.dict_name` (which is a misnomer; it's really just a reference to a dict, not a name (which one might imagine is a string)), which the caller then reads (or should, anyway).

In addition, there seems to be a bug; the second `if` block (which is never reached anyway) refers to `row`, an undefined name.

Anyway, your class doesn't need to be a class at all, and is easiest implemented with the built-in `collections.Counter()` class:

```
from collections import Counter


def bin_by_hour(dataset, value_key=None):
    counter = Counter()
    for post in dataset:
        hour = post[-1].hour  # assuming it's a `datetime` object
        if value_key:  # count using `post[value_key]`
            counter[hour] += post[value_key]
        else:  # just count
            counter[hour] += 1
    return dict(counter.items())  # make the Counter a regular dict


freq_pph = bin_by_hour(ask_posts)
freq_cph = bin_by_hour(ask_posts, value_key="num_comments")  # or whatever
```

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helped a lot.

I know it doesn't need to be a class, and indeed probably shouldn't be a class, but I'm using it as a chance to use them to learn them. I definitely learn by doing!

And now I have built-in collections.counter() to play with, too :)